# Recover photos and videos from s3 (no sd or root)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, video, photos, gallery

Basically someone deleted photos from my dads phone. He doesn't have a sd card and his Galaxy S3 is not rooted. Is there any way to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can recover data from internal memory, normal recovery softwares require the device to be in USB/ Mass Storage Mode for it to detect the device to scan.
There is one method but it requires the phone to be rooted and it's a long process. If you are interested here is the [link to it](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-internal-memory-data-recovery-yes-t1994705)

Comment: Won't rooting it make the phone lose all the data?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the mobile carrier, the phone may have pre-installed software that has been backing up various files to their servers.  For example, my S3 from Verizon has something called [Backup Assisant Plus](http://www.verizonwireless.com/wcms/consumer/products/backup-assistantplus.html) that came with the phone and was on by default.  I would check the settings in the phone and the carrier to see if the phone was sold with a default backup system.